References for Grothendieck-Verdier Duality in the original spirit
Does anyone know of good expository notes going through the theory of Verdier duality? I have been trying to read the original paper by Verdier entitled "A Duality theorem in the étale cohomology of schemes". In particular I really want to understand the theory using the original notions of notions of Nagata compactifications and the "trace morphism".
I know there have been different treatments of this by others (Hartshorne, Brain Conrad, Neeman) but these approaches are not what I am looking for.

Note that the works of Hartshorne and Neeman (at least the ones I have read) are about Grothendieck duality for coherent sheaves, which is not the same as Verdier duality for etale sheaves or constructible sheaves. It's not a different approach, it's a different problem altogether.

Étale duality was not developer by Verdier. It was introduced by Grothendieck in SGA 4 and 5. Those would be "the original references". For those who don't like SGA, there is Deligne's "Étale cohomology" (published under the label "SGA 4 1/2"). Also, there is Milne's homonymous book, but I don't know íf it's "as close to the source" as the SGAs.
